# Apache WSGI no module named django whitout virtualenv

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

wsgi.py:

```
import os,sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/html/yuyyu/yuyyu')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yuyyu.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

apache.conf:

```
...


        WSGIDaemonProcess yuyyu python-path=/var/www/html/yuyyu

        WSGIProcessGroup yuyyu
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/yuyyu/yuyyu/wsgi.py \
                 process-group=yuyyu application-group=%{GLOBAL}
 ...
```

here is my error in error.log:

```
[Fri Dec 02 19:07:55.862266 2016] [:error] [pid 1414] [remote 213.14.244.3:2784] mod_wsgi (pid=1414): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/yuyyu/yuyyu/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Dec 02 19:07:55.862323 2016] [:error] [pid 1414] [remote 213.14.244.3:2784] mod_wsgi (pid=1414): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/yuyyu/yuyyu/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Dec 02 19:07:55.862353 2016] [:error] [pid 1414] [remote 213.14.244.3:2784] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Dec 02 19:07:55.862393 2016] [:error] [pid 1414] [remote 213.14.244.3:2784]   File "/var/www/html/yuyyu/yuyyu/wsgi.py", line 23, in <module>
[Fri Dec 02 19:07:55.862398 2016] [:error] [pid 1414] [remote 213.14.244.3:2784]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Fri Dec 02 19:07:55.862418 2016] [:error] [pid 1414] [remote 213.14.244.3:2784] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

my project path is /var/www/html/yuyyu/

my wsgi file path is /var/www/html/yuyyu/yuyyu/

im get also 500 Internel Server Error and
im not using virtualenv so what can i do for solve this problem?

Comment: What python version did you use? Are you sure that django is installed for this precise version? (Are you sure you're not trying to run django with python3 after having installed django for python2 for instance?) Could you add the `pip freeze` output for the relevant python version? Are you sure as well that if you installed `django` for the correct python version, that you didn't install it just for a user but for your whole system (that you didn't use the `--user` flag with `pip`)

Comment: im using python2 here is pip freeze result: `Django==1.9.7 Landscape-Client==14.12 MySQL-python==1.2.3 PAM==0.4.2 Twisted-Core==13.2.0 apt-xapian-index==0.45 argparse==1.2.1 chardet==2.0.1 colorama==0.2.5 configobj==4.7.2 django-secure==1.0.1 django-sslserver==0.19 html5lib==0.999 pyOpenSSL==0.13 pyserial==2.6 python-apt==0.9.3.5ubuntu2 python-debian==0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2 requests==2.2.1 six==1.5.2 ssh-import-id==3.21 uWSGI==2.0.14 urllib3==1.7.1 wheel==0.24.0 wsgiref==0.1.2`

Comment: For general information on using Python virtual environments with mod_wsgi (which is recommended), see http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: Distinct from virtual environments, what does ``sys.prefix`` in interpreter for Python you have Django install output? Then use a WSGI hello world to find out what ``sys.prefix`` is that mod_wsgi is using. This will confirm they are using the same Python installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solition my django is installed to

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

and i change my .conf file like this

```
WSGIDaemonProcess yuyyu python-path=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
WSGIProcessGroup yuyyu
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/yuyyu/yuyyu/wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WSGIDaemonProcess yuyyu python-path=/var/www/html/yuyyu
```

I think that your problem is here, the `python-path` shouldn't be the path to your django project but to your python libraries (for instance the path to your python's site-packages directory where django is installed).

For me, for instance, this path is `/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages`.

Comment: i also try this
`WSGIDaemonProcess yuyyu python-path=/var/www/html/yuyyu:python-home=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
`
 but result is same

Comment: and try this :`WSGIDaemonProcess yuyyu python-path=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`  but error is still same

Comment: `WSGIDaemonProcess yuyyu python-path=/var/www/html/yuyyu:python-home=/usr/local/lib/p‌​ython2.7/site-packag‌​es` This syntax isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

In wsgi.py try to load the path where you have Django. In my configuration it is located inside of virtualenv and the path looks like that:

```
import site
site.addsitedir('~/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages')
```